# How do I remove "See Also" section from dispform.axpx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within an email I am providing a link to document libraty items using dispform.aspx as part of the link so users can view the form and if desired click on edit form to make changes.  It all works great, but the problem is the form also shows a "See Also" section that displays links underneath the "See Also" section.  This is very confusing for users.  How do I turn off the "See Also" section.

I assume I need to probably change the structure of the link, but not sure what part needs to be changed...

My link structure currently shows as below
Site URL/DocName/Forms/Dispform.aspx?ID=285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add customize the dispform.aspx page as below:

1) Go to the Library. Click on the Library tab and Select default form webparts as below:

[image]

2) Click on Edit page.

[image]

3) Click on Add a webpart > add Content editor webpart(CEWP) or script editor webpart(SEWP)

4) In the CEWP/SEWP, add the below css code:

If you are using CEWP, click on the inside of webpart and then edit source and add the below code.

If you are using SEWP, just add the below code inside the webpart.

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-recommendations-panel{display:none !important;}

</style>
```

5) Save the page. The recommendations panel will be hidden now.

[image]

Reference-

[Hide SharePoint Document Suggestions](http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Task-Doc-Suggestions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I just cheated. If you edit the page, click `Add a Web Part`, and find the content web parts you can add a `Script Editor` part. I added the following code to hide the offending element:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { $(".ms-recommendations-panel").hide(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here for a different options, here is another one:

- Navigate to your *Site settings - Master pages and page layouts -
  Display templates - System*
- Find and download **Control_Recommendations.html**
- Then open it in any notepad-like program and comment-out all `<div>` blocks inside `<body>` tag except `<div id="Control_Recommendations">` (don't forget about closing tags also).
- Then just re-upload this html-file to the same place, don't forget to Check-in item and **Publish** as main version. Js-file of the same name will also be updated, so this block will be hidden from all forms of all lists on site collection.